# "GetMap" URL from WMS layers

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, wms

I want to extract the `GetMap` URL from WMS layers with PyQGIS. For most of the WMS
layers I can extract it from `layer.source()`. However this does not
work for WMS layers where `GetMap` and `GetCapabilities` is different.
Like for [this layer](https://www.geoportal.rlp.de/mapbender/php/wms.php?inspire=1&layer_id=69694&withChilds=1&INSPIRE=1&).

The only place where I can find the `GetMap` URL is inside the
`layer.htmlMetadata()` document. From there the URL can be extracted
using regex. But every localization of QGIS (e.g. German, French ...)
has different terms for the surrounding `GetMap` HTML element. This
makes this approach quite tricky.

Is there any more elegant solution how to retrieve the `GetMap` URL from
WMS layers with PyQGIS?

PS 1: I created a workaround with `OWSlib`, but I am not happy with it, because the `WMS` needs to requested again, even though QGIS has already requested it.

PS 2: I asked the same question on the mailing list [qgis-dev](http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/QGIS-Developer-quot-GetMap-quot-URL-from-WMS-layers-td5433984.html).

Comment: In any one WMS service there is only one GetMap URL endpoint, it is not one per layer, usually but not always the same as the GetCapabilities URL endpoint.

Comment: A GetMap request is a combination of endpoint URL and request parameters based on offered values from the GetCapabilities response. You can't fetch a GetMap request for a layer, you have to construct it.

Comment: @nmtoken yes, you are right. But is there a elegant way how to get  this basic URL for GetMap? Because QGIS obviously uses it, otherwise the data could not be loaded. But I do not mangage to get it using PyQGIS

Comment: All bets are off with your example, as it doesn't appear to conform to the WMS specification ~ stated endpoint should be without request params, and param names must be case insensitive.   You could just use the `https://komserv4gdi.service24.rlp.de/ows/wms/07338019_Mutterstadt?` end point that works with `https://komserv4gdi.service24.rlp.de/ows/wms/07338019_Mutterstadt?service=WMS&request=GetCapabilities` though it's not mentioned.    Doesn't help with your PyQGIS though.